# Swiping across multiple CCLayers

Tags: delegates, cocos2d-iphone, gestures, cclayer

Imagine three instances of a `CCLayer` subclass `Block` positioned next to each other. Each is 100x100 pixels and has some basic square background art. These three objects are part of an encapsulating `CCLayer` subclass called `Container`.

**How can I swipe across the three Blocks and detect the swipe/tap/touch for each Block in Container?**

If the problem was constrained to just handling taps on `Block`s in `Container` then one could use a delegate. Something like `BlockDelegate` with a required method `userTappedBlock:(Block *) b` which would inform the `Container` whenever a `Block` is tapped.

However this approach hasn't worked for swiping yet. I get the callback in `Container` but only for the first `Block` that's tapped.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle touches in layer, that contains your blocks. Then, in `touchEnded:WithEvent:` method check what block contains touch's position.

Comment: Something like that will work. Although I think I'd check in `touchMoved` as well as `touchEnded` since I'm swiping across the layers. Anyways I just thought it would be nice for the blocks to do the touch detection for me.

Comment: Don't think that it is need. Just, for example, see how CCMenu is implemented. All the touches handles menu, not it items.

Answer (score 0):

In CustomLayer.cpp write this method for tapping the layer

void CustomLayer::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)

{

```
     CCTouch *touch = (CCTouch *) pTouches->anyObject();
     CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
     location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

         if(layer->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
                CCLog("layer Hit Test");


}
```